# Is there an error in this text's computation?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

[image]

Shouldn't there be a factor of $p$ on the right-hand side, for a result of $\mathbf P_1\{\tau_0 = \infty\} = p-q$ ? The source is [Markov Chains and Mixing Times](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact an error, but it's on the left-hand side: The $p$ shouldn't be there. The right-hand side is OK. There's a corrected version [here](http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/levin-markov.pdf) (p. $218$).

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Comment: Ah, so the corrected version is
$$
\mathbf P_1\{\tau_0=\infty\} \geqslant \mathbf P_1\left(\bigcap_{n=2}^\infty \{\tau_n<\tau_0\}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-(q/p)}{1-(q/p)^2} = \frac{p-q}p > 0.
$$
So, not giving an exact value for $\mathbf P_1\{\tau_0=\infty\}$ but instead a strictly positive lower bound. Interesting.